# Vagrant 2.2 on Win10 Error on Provider "docker"

Tags: windows, docker, vagrant

Setup :

- Vagrant 2.20
- VirtualBox 5.2.20

I reinstalled vagrant due the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654682/provider-docker-not-found-vagrant).

My Vagrantfile (ex from https://github.com/bubenkoff/vagrant-docker-example.git):

```
 # -*- mode: ruby -*-
 # vi: set ft=ruby :

 # Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
 VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
 #Check if you have the good Vagrant version to use docker provider...
 Vagrant.require_version ">= 1.6.0"

 Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
 ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'docker'
   config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
     d.build_dir = "."
     d.has_ssh = true
   end
   config.ssh.port = 22
 end
```

With the following error:

```
C:\Users\<Snip ...>\vagrant-docker-example>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'docker' provider...
The executable 'docker' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the %PATH% variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.
```

As my understanding is that vagrant automatically setups a 
Docker enabled host VM. Do I have to manual install docker in windows for that?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set Vagrant’s provider to `docker`, it will attempt to start a Docker container and do its setup there.  You do need Docker installed already.

If you’re looking for a (Linux?) VM with Docker installed, then you need to use a VM-oriented provider like `virtualbox`, and in your provisioning steps, make sure to install Docker.  In this case you need the virtualization software on your host, but you do not specifically need Docker installed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thought vagrant will do this on the fly.